# Is there a way to limit TOP rows returned by OrmLite select using Linq Expression?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

It seems like OrmLite Select(predicate) function it brings back everything in the where clause (across the network) and then applies the .Take(x) on top of that.

I need a way to only bring back the TOP x so the results are faster and use less bandwidth.

Is there a way to limit TOP rows returned by OrmLite select (using a Linq Expression)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Limit and Offset support is available using the `Limit()` expression, e.g::

#### Take 10 Rows

```
var rows = db.Select<Table>(q => q.Where(x => x.Name != null).Limit(10));
```

#### Skip 5 Rows, Take 10

```
var rows = db.Select<Table>(q => q.Where(x => x.Name != null).Limit(5,10));
```

Comment: This be done with the Expression<Func<T,bool>> overload too... var lambda = OrmExtensions.BuildLambdaDynamic<VHVIN>(search.Where);
                vehicles = db.Select<VHVIN>(q => q.Where(lambda).Limit(search.Take));